# Pod Oracle does not start correctly

Tags: oracle, kubernetes

In a Kubernetes architecture context, I am dealing with a problem that I cannot explain.

Here I have my configuration of a statefulset oracle :

```
      containers:
        - name: oracle
          image: xxxxx.xxx/oracle:**19.13.0**
          command:
            - /bin/bash
            - '-c'
            - >
              sed '/\/network\/admin\/sqlnet.ora/a echo \"SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME=1\"
              >>  \"\$ORACLE_HOME\"\/network\/admin\/sqlnet.ora' -i
              /opt/oracle/createDB.sh

              /opt/oracle/runOracle.sh
          env:
            - name: ORACLE_CHARACTERSET
              value: WE8MSWIN1252
            - name: ORACLE_PWD
              value: gOrwell1984
            - name: INIT_SGA_SIZE
              value: '7500'
            - name: INIT_PGA_SIZE
              value: '3000'
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: '4'
              memory: 8Gi
            requests:
              cpu: '2'
              memory: 4Gi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data
              mountPath: /opt/oracle/oradata
              subPath: oracle
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/sh
                - '-c'
                - >-
                  if [ -f $ORACLE_BASE/checkDBLockStatus.sh ]; then
                  $ORACLE_BASE/checkDBLockStatus.sh ; else
                  $ORACLE_BASE/checkDBStatus.sh; fi
```

I set the scale on 1 replicas. This creates a pod, at the level of the oracle container logs, when initializing the database I get this error message:

`/opt/oracle/createDB.sh: line 181:    54 Killed                  dbca -silent -createDatabase -enableArchive "$ENABLE_ARCHIVELOG" -archiveLogDest "$ARCHIVELOG_DIR" ${DBCA_CRED_OPTIONS} -responseFile "$ORACLE_BASE"/dbca.rsp` 
I'm trying to find a container level log to make this clearer but I can't find anything. Something else at the node level on the syslog logs I see an oom message :

```
Mar 12 10:54:44 k8s containerd[927]: time="2024-03-12T10:54:44.438718600Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.event.v1.publisher\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.event.v1
Mar 12 10:54:44 k8s containerd[927]: time="2024-03-12T10:54:44.438790200Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.shutdown\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.internal.v1
Mar 12 10:54:44 k8s containerd[927]: time="2024-03-12T10:54:44.438808400Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.ttrpc.v1.task\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.ttrpc.v1
Mar 12 10:54:44 k8s containerd[927]: time="2024-03-12T10:54:44.439782697Z" level=info msg="starting signal l        887 ora_svcb_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746853] [3718373] 54321 3718373  2036865    16120   708608        0           887 ora_pman_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746854] [3718377] 54321 3718377  2037952    19212   724992        0           887 ora_dia0_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746856] [3718379] 54321 3718379  2039889    19312   917504        0           887 ora_dbw0_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746857] [3718383] 54321 3718383  2037137    18807   757760        0           887 ora_lgwr_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746858] [3718387] 54321 3718387  2036880    17835   864256        0           887 ora_ckpt_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746859] [3718391] 54321 3718391  2036815    16162   729088        0           887 ora_lg00_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746860] [3718393] 54321 3718393  2036900    19850   921600        0           887 ora_smon_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746861] [3718397] 54321 3718397  2036814    15985   712704        0           887 ora_lg01_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746862] [3718399] 54321 3718399  2036863    16272   704512        0           887 ora_smco_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746863] [3718401] 54321 3718401  2037171    20274   942080        0           887 ora_reco_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746864] [3718403] 54321 3718403  2036799    15821   696320        0           887 ora_w000_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746865] [3718405] 54321 3718405  2038595    23059   995328        0           887 ora_lreg_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746867] [3718409] 54321 3718409  2036798    15811   700416        0           887 ora_w001_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746868] [3718411] 54321 3718411  2036864    15787   688128        0           887 ora_pxmn_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746869] [3718421] 54321 3718421  2037363    15050   659456        0           887 ora_d000_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746871] [3718423] 54321 3718423  2037186    14197   643072        0           887 ora_s000_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746872] [3718425] 54321 3718425  2036863    16125   708608        0           887 ora_tmon_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746873] [3718496] 54321 3718496  2036863    15773   688128        0           887 ora_mmnl_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746874] [3718498] 54321 3718498  2040737    21902   790528        0           887 ora_mmon_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746875] [3718504] 54321 3718504  2037951    17616   712704        0           887 ora_m000_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746876] [3718564] 54321 3718564  2042464    16233   753664        0           887 ora_tt00_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746877] [3718579] 54321 3718579  2036798    15670   696320        0           887 ora_tt01_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746878] [3718581] 54321 3718581  2036799    15646   700416        0           887 ora_tt02_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746880] [3718667] 54321 3718667  2036863    15688   720896        0           887 ora_cjq0_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746881] [3718668] 54321 3718668  2037725    26727  1126400        0           887 oracle_963_orcl
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746882] [3718669] 54321 3718669     2927      667    69632        0           887 datapatch
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746883] [3718671] 54321 3718671     2927      680    69632        0           887 sqlpatch
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746884] [3718676] 54321 3718676    43697    12673   327680        0           887 perl
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746885] [3718678] 54321 3718678  2063528    44426  1421312        0           887 oracle_973_orcl
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746886] [3718744] 54321 3718744  2036799    15502   720896        0           887 ora_w002_orclcd
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746887] [3718758] 54321 3718758    27466     5638   196608        0           887 sqlplus
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746888] [3718759] 54321 3718759    27341     5517   172032        0           887 sqlplus
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746890] [3718760] 54321 3718760    27341     5465   188416        0           887 sqlplus
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746891] [3718761] 54321 3718761    27341     5503   180224        0           887 sqlplus
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746892] [3718763] 54321 3718763  2038431    41224  1335296        0           887 oracle_1029_orc
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746893] [3718765] 54321 3718765  2037607    22399   905216        0           887 oracle_1031_orc
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746894] [3718767] 54321 3718767  2037609    22411   897024        0           887 oracle_1033_orc
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746895] [3718769] 54321 3718769  2037608    22370   892928        0           887 oracle_1035_orc
Mar 12 11:22:00 k8s kernel: [2759986.746896] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAoop" namespace=moby path=/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/a8856c2174a8f8d4d9e190c893e8e09b2d8c952f86a6003cbed76b9da4a7948e pid=3666469 runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2
```

But even if I increase the memory, nothing works.

If you can help me please

T

```
ssh-keygen: generating new host keys: RSA1 RSA DSA ECDSA ED25519
ORACLE EDITION: STANDARD

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 12-MAR-2024 11:19:36

Copyright (c) 1991, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
System parameter file is /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/oracle-0/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                12-MAR-2024 11:19:36
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/oracle-0/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
Prepare for db operation
8% complete
Copying database files
31% complete
Creating and starting Oracle instance
32% complete
36% complete
/opt/oracle/createDB.sh: line 181:    54 Killed                  dbca -silent -createDatabase -enableArchive "$ENABLE_ARCHIVELOG" -archiveLogDest "$ARCHIVELOG_DIR" ${DBCA_CRED_OPTIONS} -responseFile "$ORACLE_BASE"/dbca.rsp
[ 2024-03-12 11:19:44.320 UTC ] Prepare for db operation
DBCA_PROGRESS : 8%
[ 2024-03-12 11:19:44.419 UTC ] Copying database files
DBCA_PROGRESS : 31%
[ 2024-03-12 11:21:10.994 UTC ] Creating and starting Oracle instance
DBCA_PROGRESS : 32%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 36%

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Mar 12 11:22:00 2024
Version 19.13.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.13.0.0.0

SQL>    ALTER SYSTEM SET control_files='/opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/control01.ctl' scope=spfile
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-32001: write to SPFILE requested but no SPFILE is in use


SQL>
System altered.

SQL>    ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE ORCLPDB1 SAVE STATE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-65011: Pluggable database ORCLPDB1 does not exist.


SQL>
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SQL>
Session altered.

SQL>
User created.

SQL>
Grant succeeded.

SQL>
Grant succeeded.

SQL>
User altered.

SQL> SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.13.0.0.0
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle
mv: cannot stat '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/spfileORCLCDB.ora': No such file or directory

Executing user defined scripts
/opt/oracle/runUserScripts.sh: running /opt/oracle/scripts/extensions/setup/savePatchSummary.sh

DONE: Executing user defined scripts


Executing user defined scripts
/opt/oracle/runUserScripts.sh: running /opt/oracle/scripts/setup/setNLS.sh
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Mar 12 11:22:06 2024
Version 19.13.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> SQL> ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 4475
Additional information: 1135834575
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL> SQL> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> SQL> alter system set nls_length_semantics=CHAR scope=both
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL> SQL> ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 4475
Additional information: 1135834575
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL> SQL> ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
SQL> SELECT value from  V$PARAMETER WHERE NAME LIKE '%nls_length_semantics%'
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


SQL> Disconnected

DONE: Executing user defined scripts

The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle
#####################################
########### E R R O R ###############
DATABASE SETUP WAS NOT SUCCESSFUL!
Please check output for further info!
########### E R R O R ###############
#####################################
The following output is now a tail of the alert.log:
PMON (ospid: 837): terminating the instance due to ORA error 822
2024-03-12T11:22:03.323054+00:00
Cause - 'Instance is being terminated due to fatal process death (pid: 7, ospid: 859, MMAN)'
2024-03-12T11:22:03.324781+00:00
System state dump requested by (instance=1, osid=837 (PMON)), summary=[abnormal instance termination].
System State dumped to trace file /opt/oracle/diag/rdbms/orclcdb/ORCLCDB/trace/ORCLCDB_diag_868.trc
2024-03-12T11:22:04.975778+00:00
Dumping diagnostic data in directory=[cdmp_20240312112203], requested by (instance=1, osid=837 (PMON)), summary=[abnormal instance termination].
2024-03-12T11:22:06.184927+00:00
Instance terminated by PMON, pid = 837
```

he entire container log :

But even if I increase the memory, nothing works.